# Bind to UIBarButtonItem events in MvvmCross

Tags: ios, mvvmcross, xamarin.ios

What's the proper way with `MvvmCross` to create a binding from an `UIBarButtonItem` to a `MvxCommand` ?

This does not work for me ->

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    this.AddBindings (new Dictionary<object, string> (){
       {MyButton, "{'Clicked':{'Path':'MyCommand'}}"}
    });
}
```

I don't get any error in the console. I can work around by avoiding bindings, but you know, it'd look best if all was bound.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that the bar button - MyButton - is initialized before you call AddBindings, then I think your code should work.

I modified the code in WelcomeView in the Conference sample to this below and it seems to work...

```
        var s = new UIBarButtonItem()
        {
            Title = "Click me"
        };

        NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(s, false);

        this.AddBindings(new Dictionary<object, string>()
            {
                { Button1, "TouchUpInside ShowSponsorsCommand" },               
                { Button2, "TouchUpInside ShowExhibitorsCommand" },             
                { Button3, "TouchUpInside ShowMapCommand" },                
                { Button4, "TouchUpInside ShowAboutCommand" },  
            { s, "Clicked ShowMapCommand" },
            });

        //NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(new UIBarButtonItem("Tweet", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, (sender, e) => ViewModel.DoShareGeneral()), false);
```

Sorry if this 'it works for me' answer doesn't help on your machine :/

To ensure this works in Release mode, you might need to add some `UIBarButtonItem.Clicked` code somewhere.

If you want more trace from the bindings, then there is a Diagnostic Trace level you can set (but this can get quite verbose).

It might be worth checking if your `MyCommand` is being called but somehow failing - this can especially happen for things like Email, PhoneCalls, Tweets, etc which don't always work on the Simulator.

Comment: Thanks @Stuart. it works for me as well. The `canExecute` part of my `MvxCommand` was returning false :/

Comment: One thing Mvx doesn't do right now is handle the canExecute to enabled binding on any control - this can be worked around using separate enabled/disabled properties but isn't perfect.